# I'm getting Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) and don't know why?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, post, uri

I am trying send an email to my forgotPassword but it always returns me an error in console, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
```

Here's my code

```dart
 final String _url = 'apiurl.com';
 Future<String?> forgotPassword(String email) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> authData = {
      'email': email,
    };
    
    final url = Uri.http(_url, '/api/Auth/ForgotPassword', authData);

    final resp = await http.post(
      url,
      body: jsonEncode(authData),
    );
    print(url);
    print(resp.body);
```

I tried print my url and resp.body and this is what ir returned me.

URL-
http://apiurl.com/api/Auth/ForgotPassword?email=rudy%40mail.com

resp.body- Nothing/Blank

Comment: Can you show what does `_url` print ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my code, but it is basically an endpoint created baseUrl

Comment: From what I see, you should not provide the `authData` while creating the `url` , just pass it at `POST` method as you do.

Comment: I/flutter (17146): http://apiurl.com/api/Auth/ForgotPassword

E/flutter (17146): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Comment: Now it returns me this

Comment: print out `jsonEncode(authData)` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 User user = new User(email: user.email);
var response = await http.post(
  url,
  data: json.encode(user.toJson()),
);
```

Try like this.